# Why are my posts content not showing on my admin dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, plugins, postman

I have added an application to my WordPress site with a plug in that am using to automatically add posts with a python scripts. My API is working just fine even after testing on postman.
However the post Meta Desc and Key Phrase columns don't show anything as in a post added manually. (See screenshot; the first post is the one added via an api). I will appreciate any idea as to why this is.

```
post = {

    'title': question_title,
    'status': 'publish',
    "content": question,
    "type": "post",
    "categories": [2],
    "focus_keyphrase": question_title,

}
gradeboosts_url = "https://gradeboosts.com/wp-json/wp/v2"
user = 'aloy'
password = '****************'
creds = user + ':' + password
token = base64.b64encode(creds.encode())
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8')}
r = requests.post(gradeboosts_url + '/posts', json=post, headers=headers)
```

[image]

A full postman get request that is displaying all columns on wordpress:

```
response = {
    "id": 1692997,
    "date": "2021-08-13T12:43:38",
    "date_gmt": "2021-08-13T12:43:38",
    "guid": {
        "rendered": "https://gradeboosts.com/health-sciences-homework-help-3/"
    },
    "modified": "2021-08-13T12:43:38",
    "modified_gmt": "2021-08-13T12:43:38",
    "slug": "health-sciences-homework-help-3",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "link": "https://gradeboosts.com/health-sciences-homework-help-3/",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "Health Sciences homework help"
    },
    "content": {
        "rendered": "<p>Health Sciences homework help. An ion is an atom that has  gained or lost one or more electrons.</p>\n<p>                I don&#8217;t think that this is maths, but more chemistry.<br />\nAn ion is an atom that has a charge due to a lost or gain of electrons. Usually, ions occur when the atom tries to get a full outershell, either by losing electrons (and thus gaining a positive charge) or by gaining electrons (and thus getting a negative charge).</p>\n<p><a href=\"https://gradeboosts.com/health-sciences-homework-help-3\">Health Sciences homework help</a></p>\n",
        "protected": false
    },
    "excerpt": {
        "rendered": "<p>What&#8217;s an ion?</p>\n",
        "protected": false
    },
    "author": 2,
    "featured_media": 0,
    "comment_status": "open",
    "ping_status": "open",
    "sticky": false,
    "template": "",
    "format": "standard",
    "meta": {
        "spay_email": ""
    },
    "categories": [],
    "tags": [],
    "yst_prominent_words": [],
    "jetpack_featured_media_url": "",
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "https://gradeboosts.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1692997"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "https://gradeboosts.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
            }
        ],
        "about": [
            {
                "href": "https://gradeboosts.com/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post"
            }
        ],
        "author": [
            {
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://gradeboosts.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/2"
            }
        ],
        "replies": [
            {
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://gradeboosts.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=1692997"
            }
        ],
        "version-history": [
            {
                "count": 190,
                "href": "https://gradeboosts.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1692997/revisions"
            }
        ],
        "predecessor-version": [
            {
                "id": 1698135,
                "href": "https://gradeboosts.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1692997/revisions/1698135"
            }
        ],
        "wp:attachment": [
            {
                "href": "https://gradeboosts.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=1692997"
            }
        ],
        "wp:term": [
            {
                "taxonomy": "category",
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://gradeboosts.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?post=1692997"
            },
            {
                "taxonomy": "post_tag",
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://gradeboosts.com/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=1692997"
            },
            {
                "taxonomy": "yst_prominent_words",
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "https://gradeboosts.com/wp-json/wp/v2/yst_prominent_words?post=1692997"
            }
        ],
        "curies": [
            {
                "name": "wp",
                "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
                "templated": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Could your add postman request that was successful?

Comment: Is this request or response?

Comment: what i get after a post request

Comment: What I want is the postman request info in order to compare with python request, to find the differences.

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 ok, i have editted the last bit with an actual request from postman